# What is the difference beween śodaśākṣari and Pancādaśi mantras?

Tags: mantras

I would like to know the difference between the Pancādaśi and śodaśākṣari(षोडशाक्षरि) mantras, of course apart from the fact that the later contains one more akshara.

Why is the śodaśākṣari kept so secret?

If you don't know about the [**Panchadasi**](http://www.manblunder.com/articlesview/panchadasi-mantra-explained), here is the explanation.

Comment: Are u the owner of that blog?I used to read the blog sometime back..and i thought u urself is some kind of an expert or a sampradaya guru..

Comment: No I'm not the owner of that blog..I'm an avid reader of that blog only.